# Connected Subset of Finite Topological Space

Tags: analysis

What I want to know is this:

Am I correct in thinking that if we have a finite topological space (so no reals or anything here), that any connected subset contained in this space has only one element? For example, {x} is connected but {x,y} is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

No; as a simple case, if any space $X$ has the indiscrete topology (only the empty set and $X$ are open), then *any* subset of $X$ is connected.

In more detail: Suppose $V \subset X$.  Then the relative topology on $V$ is also the indiscrete topology.  Thus $V$ has no open subsets other than the empty set and $V$, and is therefore connected.

Comment: I am so sorry to have to ask you again but this topic in analysis is flying over my head. If I take a subset of X and it is open, and has two elements, then why can I not form a separation with those two elements?

Comment: @user138798 If $X$ has the indiscrete topology, there are no open subsets of $X$ other than $\emptyset$ and $X$.  See edits.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. Just bear with me for one last thing. I now understand what the subsets of X are. Does it matter what elements X has?

Comment: @user138798 No it doesn't (other than trivialities, like $X$ having one element or no elements) - the indiscrete topology is defined the same way for every set.